# Unit testing for IBAction connection with good form

Tags: swift, unit-testing

I've created a successful unit test that checks for an IBAction in Swift. However, the form isn't great:

```
func testAddButtonIBActionShouldExist() {
    let actions=viewController.addButton.actionsForTarget(viewController, forControlEvent: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    XCTAssertNotNil(actions, "Add button should have conections")

    if actions != nil{
        let actionsAsNSArray:NSArray=actions! as NSArray
        XCTAssertTrue(actionsAsNSArray.containsObject("addNumbers:"), "Add button not connected to correct IBAction")
    }
}
```

It separates the test for nil and the `containsObject` into two separate parts, and also includes an `if`… both of which I believe are bad unit testing form. Is there a way to somehow combine these in Swift 1.2 (or Swift 2)? Thanks for reading.

Comment: I use guard to make such things nicer: http://swiftandpainless.com/using-guard-in-unit-tests/

Comment: @dasdom Interesting, I should give guard a closer look! Thanks for the comment.